# Javascript Function only work at first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My problem is that when I click on row add button I cannot get the javascript function call again. It shows the result in the first attempt but when I click on row add then it doesn't work. Help me in this regards thank you.

**Detail:**
I have three inputs as rate quantity and amount. When I fill out the inputs for rate and quantity for the first time. I get the amount automatically by function call in javascript. When I click on add row button then after this I cannot get the amount again automatically. It seems like it doesn't call the function again. Below is the code I hope someone can solve my small problem.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


          function addRow(tableID) {



            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);


                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;


                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
//                    case "text":
  //                          newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    //                        break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;


                }

            }
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 1500 }, 'slow'); 
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }

            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>


<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



function manage() {



var c=document.getElementById("quantity").value ;
var b=document.getElementById("rate").value ;
    var add= c*b ;

var d=document.getElementById("amount");

    d.value=add;
}




    </SCRIPT>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--------------------------------------Rows Adder----------------------------------------->


<head>
<style>

   input:focus
   {
        background:none;
        border-bottom: solid #3B5998;
        outline: none;
   }

</style>
<link href="css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/hover/Hover-master/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  <script src="row_adder.js">
</script>


</head>

<body onLoad="addr()">
<form style="font-family: arial, sans-serif" action="order_form_db.php" method="post" onSubmit="return check(this)">

  <div >
    <br><br>
   <div align="center">
     <table  cellspacing="2" cellspacing="2"  id="dataTablee">

       <tr>

         <th></th> 

         <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Rate</th>
         <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Quantity</th>
         <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Amount</th>




       </tr>

       <tr >

        <td ><input type="checkbox"  name="chk[]" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="delete_box"/></td>       


         <td height="20px"><input id="rate" class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20"  type="number"  width="76px" name="rate[]" required></td>

         <td height="20px"><input id="quantity" class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20"  type="number"  width="76px" name="quantity[]" onKeyPress="manage()" onKeyDown="manage()" onKeyUp="manage()" ></td>

         <td height="20px"><input id="amount" class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20"  type="number"  width="76px" name="amount[]" ></td>

         </tr>
     </table>
     <br>

<table>

 <th  style="font-size:14px">&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount Recieved</th> 

     <td> 
        <input  id="rec" class="txtBox"  type="number" name="arecieve" />
     </td>

</table>


           <div align="center">
    <input class="hvr-glow" type="button" id="button1" class="login_button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTablee')"  /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input class="hvr-glow" type="button" id="button2" class="login_button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTablee')" />  <br><br>  
    <input class="hvr-glow" type="submit" id="button3" value="Save" name="Save" align="middle">
  </div>


 </form>
```

Comment: use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (because your code has jQuery) and Event delegation:

```
$(document).on('input', '[name="quantity[]"]', manage);
```

Further, when you're adding a new row duplicates IDs are being created.  So, remove the IDs and work with names.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }

  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: 1500
  }, 'slow');
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }

    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

function manage() {
  var c = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="quantity[]"]').val();

  var b = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="rate[]"]').val();
  var add = c * b;

  var d = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="amount[]"]').val(add);
}

$(document).on('input', '[name="quantity[]"]', manage);
```

```css
input:focus {
  background: none;
  border-bottom: solid #3B5998;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="font-family: arial, sans-serif" action="order_form_db.php" method="post" onSubmit="return check(this)">

  <div>
    <br><br>
    <div align="center">
      <table cellspacing="2" cellspacing="2" id="dataTablee">

        <tr>

          <th></th>

          <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Rate</th>
          <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Quantity</th>
          <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-size:14px" width="79" align="center">Amount</th>




        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="delete_box" /></td>


          <td height="20px"><input class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20" type="number" width="76px" name="rate[]" required></td>

          <td height="20px"><input class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20" type="number" width="76px" name="quantity[]"></td>

          <td height="20px"><input class="txtBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" size="20" type="number" width="76px" name="amount[]"></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>

      <table>

        <th style="font-size:14px">&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount Recieved</th>

        <td>
          <input id="rec" class="txtBox" type="number" name="arecieve" />
        </td>

      </table>


      <div align="center">
        <input class="hvr-glow" type="button" id="button1" class="login_button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTablee')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="hvr-glow" type="button" id="button2" class="login_button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTablee')" /> <br><br>
        <input class="hvr-glow" type="submit" id="button3" value="Save" name="Save" align="middle">
      </div>


</form>
```